# terminate adding elements to List in method Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to add multiple conditions to the method in the class `'PracownikNauk'`, so that I can do the following:

1) add elements to the`PracownikNauk`, of both types like `Cwiczenia` or `Wyklad`, only if his field `typ` is `Wykladowca`, so to do that I added to my method which is called `dodajZajecia` this condition:

```
   public void dodajZajecia(Zajecia m) { 

    List <Zajecia> przypisane = new ArrayList <Zajecia>();

    if ((typ.equals("Prowadzacy cwiczenia")) && (m instanceof Wyklad)) {

    System.out.println("Prowadzacy cwiczenia nie moze prowadzic wykladow"); }

     else { przypisane.add(m);

    System.out.println(m.toString() + toString()); }
```

And it works. But I also need to make a condition to the ArrayList that I cannot add more than 3 elements, but I should be able to add them just by calling my method `dodajZajecia` every time, so like adding elements one by one, and if 4th element is added  a message in console should appear that `3 Lessons are maximum per one Lecturer`. And I don't really get how to do that, as I need to simply call my method `dodajZajecia` in the `main` method.

I will just show code from the main method so there is an idea of the algorithm:

```
 public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Wyklad wyklad1 = new Wyklad("Programowanie w Javie", "PGJ", 1, "wyklad");
    Cwiczenia zajecia1 = new Cwiczenia("Programowanie w Javie", "PGJ", 1,         "cwiczenia");
    Wyklad wyklad2 = new Wyklad("Programowanie obiektowe", "PGO", 1, "wyklad");
    Cwiczenia zajecia2 = new Cwiczenia("Programowanie obiektowe", "PGO",1, "cwiczenia");
    Cwiczenia zajecia3 = new Cwiczenia("Technologie internetu", "TIN", 1, "cwiczenia");
    Cwiczenia zajecia4 = new Cwiczenia("Java swing","SWI",1,"cwiczenia");

    PracownikAdm admin1 = new PracownikAdm("Jaroslaw", "Kowal", 2000, "pracownik fizyczny");
    PracownikNauk wykladowca1 = new PracownikNauk("wykladowca","Ireneusz","Mak",2200,"magister");
    PracownikNauk wykladowca2 = new PracownikNauk("wykladowca", "Eugeniusz", "Klos", 2500, "doktor");
    PracownikNauk prCw1 = new PracownikNauk("Prowadzacy cwiczenia", "Truong", "Le",2100,"magister");
    PracownikNauk prCw2 = new PracownikNauk("Prowadzacy cwiczenia", "Mateusz", "Szerszen", 2200, "magister");

    Osoba [] pracownicy = new Osoba [5];
    pracownicy[0] = admin1;
    pracownicy[1] = wykladowca1;
    pracownicy[2]=  wykladowca2;
    pracownicy[3]=  prCw1;
    pracownicy[4]=  prCw2;

    for (Osoba pracownicy1: pracownicy) {
        pracownicy.toString();
        System.out.println(pracownicy1);
    }

    wykladowca1.dodajZajecia(wyklad1);
    wykladowca1.dodajZajecia(zajecia1);
    wykladowca2.dodajZajecia(zajecia2);

        prCw1.dodajZajecia(wyklad2);
        prCw1.dodajZajecia(zajecia1);
        prCw1.dodajZajecia(zajecia3);


        prCw1.dodajZajecia(zajecia4);
        prCw1.dodajZajecia(zajecia3);
        }



}
```

So for the 4th adding of element `prCw1` there should be a message in console that `3 elements are maximum`

I tried to add `while` loop after `else` but it didn't help, adding a `set Size` but it then adds three of elements I wanted to add once to the particular `PracownikNauk`, so is there a different method to add this second condition to  the method `dodajZajecia`??

Comment: A general tip: try coding in english. While it is of course possible to read your code it certainly would help to know the names of the variables as a hint to their purpose.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what language is that?

Comment: Thanks, you are right, polish is not a universal language

Comment: yep, thats polish. Im sorry, I know it looks a bit like chinese :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly. Calling `dodajZajecia` will continue to add elements to the array regardless of any limit you've set in the method because you're creating a new `ArrayList` every time.

Instead, try defining `List <Zajecia> przypisane = new ArrayList <Zajecia>();` as an instance-variable of the class containing the `dodajZajecia` method. This way, `prCw1` will have a single `List` to which it will add items, instead of every method execution having its own `List`.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. It works as a class field and defined size :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but I think you just want to make sure you don't add more than three elements to an ArrayList. If so, given the code you have, its as simple as:

```
if(przypisane.size() >= 3)
{
   System.out.println("No more than 3 lectuers per class permitted");
}
else
{
  // Add the element here and do whatever
}
```

But you said something about calling the method more than once, in which case you have an issue, because you create a new ArrayList in that same method.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the length of the arraylist in dodajZajecia before adding elements. If the length is <3 then add it else print out the error statement.

public void dodajZajecia(Zajecia m) {

```
List <Zajecia> przypisane = new ArrayList <Zajecia>();

if ((typ.equals("Prowadzacy cwiczenia")) && (m instanceof Wyklad)) {

System.out.println("Prowadzacy cwiczenia nie moze prowadzic wykladow"); }

 else { 
    if(przypisane.size()<3){
    przypisane.add(m);

    System.out.println(m.toString() + toString());
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("3 Lessons are maximum per one Lecturer");
    } 
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Method keeps on adding the elements to the same prCw1.

Comment: I mean is that it cant add more than three elements to the same object of class ParcownikNauk.

Answer (score 0):

I am .NET dev for years now, but Java is very similar. M. Brynczka pointed out correctly your problem: your function is redefining lesson list for each call. Your class should look like this:

```
public class Main {
    static List <Zajecia> przypisane =  = new ArrayList <Zajecia>();

    public static void dodajZajecia(Zajecia m) { 
        if ((typ.equals("Prowadzacy cwiczenia")) && (m instanceof Wyklad)) 
            System.out.println("Prowadzacy cwiczenia nie moze prowadzic wykladow"); 
        else { 
             przypisane.add(m);
             System.out.println(m.toString() + toString()); 
        }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Wyklad wyklad1 = new Wyklad("Programowanie w Javie", "PGJ", 1, "wyklad");
       Cwiczenia zajecia1 = new Cwiczenia("Programowanie w Javie", "PGJ", 1,         "cwiczenia");
       Wyklad wyklad2 = new Wyklad("Programowanie obiektowe", "PGO", 1, "wyklad");
       Cwiczenia zajecia2 = new Cwiczenia("Programowanie obiektowe", "PGO",1, "cwiczenia");
       Cwiczenia zajecia3 = new Cwiczenia("Technologie internetu", "TIN", 1, "cwiczenia");
       Cwiczenia zajecia4 = new Cwiczenia("Java swing","SWI",1,"cwiczenia");

       PracownikAdm admin1 = new PracownikAdm("Jaroslaw", "Kowal", 2000, "pracownik fizyczny");
       PracownikNauk wykladowca1 = new PracownikNauk("wykladowca","Ireneusz","Mak",2200,"magister");
       PracownikNauk wykladowca2 = new PracownikNauk("wykladowca", "Eugeniusz", "Klos", 2500, "doktor");
       PracownikNauk prCw1 = new PracownikNauk("Prowadzacy cwiczenia", "Truong", "Le",2100,"magister");
       PracownikNauk prCw2 = new PracownikNauk("Prowadzacy cwiczenia", "Mateusz", "Szerszen", 2200, "magister");

       Osoba [] pracownicy = new Osoba [5];
       pracownicy[0] = admin1;
       pracownicy[1] = wykladowca1;
       pracownicy[2]=  wykladowca2;
       pracownicy[3]=  prCw1;
       pracownicy[4]=  prCw2;

       for (Osoba pracownicy1: pracownicy) {
           pracownicy.toString();
           System.out.println(pracownicy1);
       }

       wykladowca1.dodajZajecia(wyklad1);
       wykladowca1.dodajZajecia(zajecia1);
       wykladowca2.dodajZajecia(zajecia2);

       prCw1.dodajZajecia(wyklad2);
       prCw1.dodajZajecia(zajecia1);
       prCw1.dodajZajecia(zajecia3);


       prCw1.dodajZajecia(zajecia4);
       prCw1.dodajZajecia(zajecia3);
   }
}
```

An alternative is to define `dodajZajecia` in the Main class (outside all methods) and send as a parameter to the function `dodajZajecia`.

Comment: yeah, I got it, added Array list as a class field and removed from the method